# How does difficulty in Salmon Run work?

Tags: splatoon-3

I've never played Splatoon before 3, so even if its unchanged in 2... I wouldn't know that either.

When I first started, Salmon Run was pretty much able to be solo'd, but now that I've played a bit and hover around Profressional+1/+2. It's much more difficult. I'm not able to choose the difficulty anywhere even though it definitely changed. So I have a question with follow-ups.

Does matchmaking have set difficulties for each "Pay Rank"? If it does, am I only matched with people in the same Pay Rank? Finally, knowing all that... is the only way to lower the difficulty to lose a whole bunch of rounds on purpose to lower my pay rank(this would probably not go well with my team mates)? I liked the mode to just chill and co-op after the sweaty pvp gametypes, but even this is getting too stressful.

Comment: Dont have the exact table for splatoon3, but here is how it worked in splatoon 2. https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Salmon_Run_data Basically difficulty depends on the total rank points of the players.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that you actually can sort of indirectly choose the difficulty. If you press ZL just before entering queue, you can "demote yourself" to the next lowest rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Splatoon 3 wikia](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Salmon_Run_Next_Wave):
The quota and Hazard Level is determined by the sum of the ranking of all players within match.

The hazard level of a shift determines both the difficulty of the shift, such as how many bosses spawn in a time period, and determines the odds of getting silver or gold scales from an Xtrawave encounter. The hazard level is determined by a formula using the combined rank of all players in the shift.
The hazard level for a completed shift can be checked by opening the Recent Jobs list from the menu in Grizzco or via SplatNet 3, which can be used to estimate what the hazard level of the next shift will be.

The following table shows a list of known value ranges for the average of 4 players' ranks within the same Job Title:

[image]